# Query parameter not working for the API end point

Tags: powerquery, m

I am recently trying to learn about basics of extracting data from APIs and was playing around with an opensource API website extracting data using power query. I have managed to extract country data using one get request and as a next step I was trying to combine two GET requests i.e. to use first GET request to fetch the list of 25 country ISO codes and using that list to filter for cities in the city end point, but unfortunately its throwing an error saying internal server error. I suspect it is an issue with the source rather than my code but do not have enough knowledge or experience to confirm that. The two endpoints (Country and City) work individually I can extract the full data using two queries and the combine filter etc. in power query, but was wondering if the error I am getting is due to issue with the source or my code which is pasted below?

```
let 
themainurl= ("https://api.openaq.org/v2/countries"),
limit = "25",
Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(themainurl, [Query =[limit = limit]])),
    results = Source[results],
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(results, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"code", "name", "locations", "firstUpdated", "lastUpdated", "parameters", "count", "cities", "sources"}, {"code", "name", "locations", "firstUpdated", "lastUpdated", "parameters", "count", "cities", "sources"}),
    #"CountryCode" = #"Expanded Column1"[code],
    ParamISO_Code = #"CountryCode",
 cityurl = "https://api.openaq.org/v2/cities"  ,
Source1 = Json.Document(Web.Contents(cityurl,[Query=[country = ParamISO_Code,limit = "2"]])),
    results1 = Source1[results]

in
   results1
```

As mentioned above I have tried the endpoints seperately without any query parameters and its working fine and I can extract full data.

I have worked through API help link on the website and tried each query parameters on there

https://docs.openaq.org/reference/cities_get_v2_cities_get

I have got the `Limit`, `Page` parameters working, but `country_id`, `country` is not working at all and there is something fishy going on with `city` parameter too. I have tried to filter the data using `city` within the code but its seems to be pulling through everything (didn't throw the error I got while using `country` or `country_id` parameter):

```
let 

 cityurl = "https://api.openaq.org/v2/cities"  ,
Source1 = Json.Document(Web.Contents(cityurl,[Query = [ciy ="Alba"]])),
    results = Source1[results],
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(results, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"country", "city", "count", "locations", "firstUpdated", "lastUpdated", "parameters"}, {"country", "city", "count", "locations", "firstUpdated", "lastUpdated", "parameters"})
in
    #"Expanded Column1"
```

I understand that is quite a lot of detail for a problem which may be too silly, but hopefully someone can shed some light in my learning path.

Comment: [ci**t**y ="Alba"] missing the t there